# Spring boot RequestBody getting null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I'm new in Spring Boot, i have a little issue when i'm getting JSON in my RestController from Postman.

When i send the request from Postmat with its attributes it's always getting null in the RequestBody.

This is my Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/enviar",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class EnviarAdicionService {
    @Autowired
    private final EnviarAdicionUseCase enviarAdicionUseCase;
    @Autowired
    private final GuardarLogUseCase guardarLogUseCase;

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private String _statusCode;
    private Date dateStart;


    @PostMapping
    public DatosAdicionResponse PostAdicionFondos(@RequestBody @Valid RequestAdicion requestAdicion){
          //PostMapping logic
          ...
    }
}
```

My RequestAdicion is like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestAdicion implements Serializable {
    private final static String regExpression = "\\{\\[sw\\.,ñÑ]\\+\\$}";
    @RequestHeaderValidation
    private RequestHeader Header;
    @CuentaValidation(NumeroIdentificacionName = "NumeroDocumentoCuentaOrigen", TipoIdentificacionName = "TipoDocumentoCuentaOrigen",
            TipoCuentaDepositosName = "TipoCuentaDepositoOrigen", NumeroCuentaDepositoName = "NumeroCuentaDepositoOrigen",
            EntidadCuentaName = "EntidadCuentaOrigen", TipoCuentaName = "TipoCuentaOrigen", NumeroCuentaName = "NumeroCuentaOrigen",
            CodigoFondoName = "CodigoFondoCuentaOrigen", EntidadCuentaDepositoName = "EntidadCuentaDepositoOrigen")
    private CuentaOrigen CuentaOrigen;
    @CuentaFondoValidation(TipoIdentificacionName = "TipoDocumentoCuentaDestino", NumeroIdentificacionFondoName = "NumeroDocumentoCuentaDestino",
            EntidadName = "EntidadCuentaDestino", CodigoFondoName = "CodigoFondoCuentaDestino",
            NumeroFondoInversionName = "NumeroFondoInversionCuentaDestino")
    private CuentaFondo CuentaDestino;
    @FormaDePagoValidation
    @Pattern(regexp = regExpression,message = "Valor no permitido. FormaDePago")
    private String FormaDePago;
    @ValorValidation
    private double ValorAdicion;
    @OficinaValidation
    private long Oficina;
    @CanalValidation
    @Pattern(regexp = regExpression,message = "Valor no permitido. Canal")
    private String Canal;
}
```

I'm sending these attributes in Postman

```
Headers
Content-Type: application/json

Body
{
    "Header": {
        "SystemId": "AW1371",
        "MessageId": "1234567890120006",
        "UserName": "autWakanda",
        "Destination": {
            "Name": null,
            "NameSpace": null,
            "Operation": null
        }
    },
    "CuentaOrigen": {
    "NumeroDocumentoCuentaOrigen": 8232166,
    "TipoDocumentoCuentaOrigen": "1",
    "TipoCuentaDepositoOrigen": "7",
    "NumeroCuentaDepositoOrigen": "40673760005",
    "EntidadCuentaOrigen": "00007",
    "TipoCuentaOrigen": "7",
    "NumeroCuentaOrigen": "40673760005",
    "CodigoFondoCuentaOrigen": "123"
  },
  "CuentaDestino": {
    "TipoDocumentoCuentaDestino": "1",
    "NumeroDocumentoCuentaDestino": 1360740,
    "NumeroFondoInversionCuentaDestino": "0021008106434090",
    "EntidadCuentaDestino": "00532",
    "CodigoFondoCuentaDestino": "21"
  },
  "FormaDePago": "72",
  "ValorAdicion": 133000.31,
  "Oficina": 3132,
  "Canal": "SVE"
}
```

I tried to set the first character in lowercase but it doesn't work.

This is the exception raised:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "co.com.bancolombia.model.requestheader.RequestHeader.getSystemId()" because the return value of "co.com.bancolombia.api.models.RequestAdicion.getHeader()" is null
```

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: I solved the problem setting the annotation @JsonProperty to each field, and creating to each model a NoArgsConstructor initializing variables with no value and the annotation @AllArgsConstructor in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your case. AFAIK, by default spring uses camelCase even if you use PascalCase (or UpperCamelCase) for your fields.

I suggest you using camelCase in stead, but if you need to stick to pascal case you should add:
`@JsonProperty("Header")` on your header field (and do the same for other fields.

you could also tweak the objectMapper to do this without the annotations.

Comment: I put the JsonProperty in each field, but now the exception is this:

```Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `co.com.bancolombia.model.requestheader.RequestHeader` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)```

I have Data and NoArgsConstructor Lombok annotations in my data class

Comment: add a file called lombok.config in the project root and put this line in:
`lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true`
and probably also put in `config.stopBubbling=true`

Comment: Didn't work for me, i'll keep trying, but thanks for your help

Comment: It seems the RequestHeader class is the problem. Make sure all your model classes (also for your fields) have appropriate constructors (either noArgs, or with @JsonCreator or with constructorProperties added through lombok)
However, I believe I did answers your original question, so to accept the answer would be appropriate

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue for a different reason, so I'm adding this quick note to maybe help someone else.
I couldn't figure why my controller parameter annotated as @RequestBody was coming thru as all blank/empty.  Already checked Content-Type: application/json.

I wasted a lot of time on this before realizing my IDE had chosen a totally wrong import for that annotation class.
So just make sure you've got

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
```

and not some other RequestBody class in your imports.